# Room DAO with inherited interfaces

Tags: android, android-room

I have a **DAO** interface, of which I have multiple implementations and I want one of them to be a Room implementation (**Kotlin**):

```
interface BaseDao {
    fun getAll(): Single<List<SomeData>>
    fun insert(data: List<SomeData>)
}
```

and my Room (RxRoom) interface:

```
@Dao
interface RxRoomBaseDao: BaseDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM some_data")
    override fun getAll(): Single<List<SomeData>>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    override fun insert(data: List<SomeData>)
}
```

It looks like the Room compiler tries to compile the `BaseDao` instead of the `RxRoomBaseDao` and complains `error: Dao class must be annotated with @Dao` and for both methods `error: A DAO method can be annotated with only one of the following:Insert,Delete,Query,Update`.

I have also tried an abstract class for the `RxRoomBaseDao` with the same result.

Is this a known bug or limitation of the Room compiler? How can I achieve what I want without polluting my `BaseDao` with Room's annotations?

Comment: Why dont't you add @Dao to BaseDao?

Answer (score 10):

It seems OP has since moved on from Room, but fwiw, it's possible to use generics to solve this problem:

```
interface BaseDao<T> {
    @Insert
    fun insert(vararg obj: T)
}
@Dao
abstract class DataDao : BaseDao<Data>() {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM Data")
    abstract fun getData(): List<Data>
}
```

Check out the "Use DAO's inheritance capability" section in this [Official Room blog post](https://medium.com/google-developers/7-pro-tips-for-room-fbadea4bfbd1)

Answer (score 0):

Create your dao as an abstract class:

```
@Dao
public abstract class EntityDao implements Base {

   @Override
   @Query("SELECT * FROM " + Entity.TABLE_NAME)
   public abstract Flowable<List<Entity>> getEntities();
}

interface Base {
   Flowable<List<Entity>> getEntities();
}
```

Comment: I tried this back then, as mentioned in the question, and it gave the same error. Did something change since then? I have abandoned the Room already...

Comment: Kotlin represents `interface` as an `abstract class` to JVM, so that you inherit `abstract class` from `abstract class` and Room fails. This answer will be right, if converted to java.

Answer (score 0):

my `BaseDao` interface:

```
@Dao
interface BaseDao<T> {

    /**
     * Insert an entity into the table.
     *
     * @param entity The entity to insert.
     */
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insert(entity: T)

    /**
     * Insert multiple entities into the table.
     *
     * @param entities The list of entities to insert.
     */
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertAll(entities: List<T>)

    /**
     * Update an entity in the table.
     *
     * @param entity The entity to update.
     */
    @Update
    suspend fun update(entity: T)

    /**
     * Delete an entity from the table.
     *
     * @param entity The entity to delete.
     */
    @Delete
    suspend fun delete(entity: T)
}
```

you can use it like this:

```
@Dao
interface PointDao : BaseDao<Point> {

   // custom queries goes here...

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Point")
    fun getAll(): Flow<List<Point>>
}
```